# Why does my colored cube not work with GL_BLEND?

Tags: c++, opengl, blend

My cube isn't rendering as expected when I use GL_BLEND.

```
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE);
```

I'm also having a similar problem with drawing some semi-opaque vertices in front, which could well be related.

> Related: [Why do my semi-opaque vertices make background objects brighter in OpenGL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722033/why-do-my-semi-opaque-vertices-make-background-objects-brighter-in-opengl)

Here's what it's supposed to look like:

[Normal cube http://img408.imageshack.us/img408/2853/normalcube.png](http://img408.imageshack.us/img408/2853/normalcube.png)

And here's what it actually looks like:

[Dark cube http://img7.imageshack.us/img7/7133/darkcube.png](http://img7.imageshack.us/img7/7133/darkcube.png)

Please see the code used to [create the colored cube](http://pastebin.com/f5393f089), and the code used to actually [draw the cube](http://pastebin.com/f4aa216b6).

The cube is being drawn like so:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();

// ... do some translation, rotation, etc ...

drawCube();

glPopMatrix();

// ... swap the buffers ...
```

Comment: Did you get the first picture from your program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try disabling all lighting before drawing the cube:

```
glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have lighting enabled on the second one,

try with a glShadeModel( GL_FLAT ) before drawing,

Answer (score 0):

This has me stomped. What it looks like is that some vertices have some alpha values that are non-opaque. However the code you posted has all 1. for alpha. So... in order to debug more, did you try to change your clear color to something non-black ? Say green ?
From the code, I doubt lighting is turned on, since no normals were specified.

Last comment, offtopic... You should really not use `glBegin`/`glEnd` (2 function calls per vertex + 2 per primitive is really not a good usage of the recent developments in OpenGL). Try `glDrawElements` with `QUAD_LIST`, or even better, `TRIANGLE_LIST`. You already have the data nicely laid out for that.