# Why do my semi-opaque vertices make background objects brighter in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, opacity

I am rendering 4 vertices (a square) in front of a colored cube. The vertices are colored white, but are blended at 0.5f.

> Related: [Why does my colored cube not work with GL_BLEND?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721998/why-does-my-colored-cube-not-work-with-glblend)

Please could someone tell me why the colored cube appears brighter when obscured by the semi-opaque square?

Cube rendered without square in front:

[Normal cube http://img408.imageshack.us/img408/2853/normalcube.png](http://img408.imageshack.us/img408/2853/normalcube.png)

And, rendered with the square:

[Cube with square http://img142.imageshack.us/img142/6255/brightsquare.png](http://img142.imageshack.us/img142/6255/brightsquare.png)

Please see the code used to [create the colored cube](http://pastebin.com/f5393f089), the code used to actually [draw the cube](http://pastebin.com/f4aa216b6), and the [code where the cube and square are rendered](http://pastebin.com/f2966e1fe).

This is the code in my init function:

```
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE);
```

Comment: All your links direct to the same segment of code

Comment: Damn, thanks for the heads up! Fixed now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say it's because your semi-transparent square gets added to the existing pixels, thus incrementing their intensity.

The [documentation for `glBlendFunc()`](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/man_pages/hardcopy/GL/html/gl/blendfunc.html) recommends setting the second parameter to `GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA`, that is the boilerplate for implementing transparency. Try it.

Comment: Yeah, looks like a white translucent square, I don't see the problem.